# Haskell's bed-and-breakfast matrix multiplication is wrong?

Tags: haskell, matrix, linear-algebra

Haskell's bed-and-breakfast library is the first library in the Linear algebra section in https://wiki.haskell.org/Applications_and_libraries/Mathematics.
So, I'm trying:

```
let a = Matrix.fromList [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
let b = Matrix.fromList [[1], [2], [3]]
a * b
*** Exception: Matrix.times: `numRows a' and `numCols b' don't match.
```

Wat? If I multiply [m x n] matrix by [n x p] matrix I should get [m x p] matrix, not this silly exception. Ok, maybe library author doesn't know where is left and where is right.

```
b * a
 *** Exception: Ix{Int}.index: Index (2) out of range ((1,1))
```

Waaaaat?

Comment: The first error looks wrong: the source code is ``... | numCols a /= numRows b = error "Matrix.times: `numRows a' and `numCols b' don't match."`` which is eyebrow-raising ...

Comment: @chi That's the source code for the most recent release, yes -- but I bet OP isn't using the most recent release!

Comment: @DanielWagner If that's the latest release, it still looks wrong! I also checked the github and the error is still there... Am I missing anything?

Comment: @chi The text of the error is backwards (actually ambiguous, because who the heck knows which argument is `a` and which is `b` without reading the source of `times`?) -- but the actual check is right. And in the old release, the text of the error matched the (wrong) check -- so it was semantically wrong but at least it was accurate to what the code actually did!

Comment: I had never heard of this library until now. I would recommend the static part of hmatrix https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix-0.17.0.1/docs/Numeric-LinearAlgebra-Static.html. This catches row / column mismatches at compile time rather than run time. You can see an example here in an implementation of a Kalman filter: https://idontgetoutmuch.wordpress.com/2015/05/31/the-flow-of-the-thames-an-autoregressive-model/. The plethora of type signatures are mainly there to help the reader; most can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet that you are using a newish GHC; and as a result cabal chose an oldish version of bed-and-breakfast. On my machine, it chose version 0.1.2 (even though the latest version is 0.4.3); this version appears to have an [incorrect dimensions check in its multiplication function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bed-and-breakfast-0.1.2/docs/src/Numeric-Matrix.html#line-222):

```
a `times` b
    | numRows a /= numCols b = error "Matrix.times: `numRows a' and `numCols b' don't match."
    | otherwise = fromList [ [ row i a `dotProd` col j b
                             | j <- [1..numCols b] ]
                           | i <- [1..numRows a] ]
```

That check should be `numCols a /= numRows b`. The check is fixed in later versions of the library; but these versions also (correctly) specify upper bounds on `base` that exclude new GHCs.

Therefore I suspect that you will either have to update the library to work with new GHCs, patch the old version of the library, or use a more actively maintained library. I've been happy with [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) in the past, though note that matrix multiplication is spelled `(<>)`, not `(*)`.

Comment: Thanks. Cabal really chose 0.1.2 version. Last time I tried to build hmatrix on windows it takes 2 days and led me to nowhere. So I'd better use Python or Matlab..

Comment: @user834108 You could also consider using `cabal unpack bed-and-breakfast-0.1.2` to get a copy of the source, fix the check, and `cabal install` the result, if you're really set on "bed-and-breakfast or nothing".

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the [Numeric.Matrix documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bed-and-breakfast-0.4.3/docs/Numeric-Matrix.html).

> The innermost lists represent the rows. This function will create a m-n-matrix, where m is the number of rows, which is the minimum length of the row lists and n is the number of columns, i.e. the length of the outer list.

This is... difficult to parse, but it means that `[[1], [2], [3]]` is a 1x3 matrix, *not* a 3x1 matrix.  This matches the assertion that the number of columns is the length of the outer list--which of course implies that each inner list is itself a column.

Using the phrase "row-major order" would make things clearer.  For reference, Fortran is row-major, C is column-major.  Most linear algebra packages seem to follow Fortran conventions, so the bed-and-breakfast library is fairly normal in that regard.

As for the exception... sounds like a bug?

Comment: Ok, thanks. But `[[1], [2], [3]]` is displayed (show b) like `1\n 2\n 3\n`.. It's really confusing.

Comment: Yep.  I would probably choose a different library.

Comment: I think `fromList [[1],[2],[3]]` is indeed intended to be a 3x1 matrix. Since `[[1], [2], [3]]` has three inner-most lists, it has three rows. This seems to mesh perfectly well with the documentation in my reading.

Comment: Then how is "the number of columns" equal to "the length of the outer list"?  Perhaps the documentation is incorrect or contradictory.  At a bare minimum, the documentation is poor.

Comment: @DietrichEpp ...you're right, that excerpt is a mess. Somehow I managed to not even read the second sentence before I wrote my comment. Having the number of rows be the minimum length of any row is... just clearly wrong.